# How to add a role to a specific user with a bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Do you know how to add a role to a specific user with a slash command

interaction.member.roles.add()

but what i really want it's a thing like that:

```
else if (interaction.commandName === "bantemp") {
    if (interaction.memberPermissions.has("BanMembers")) {
        const options1 = interaction.options.getUser("utilisateur");
        const options2 = interaction.options.getString("raison");
        const user = options1;
        const raison = options2;
        const role = "1144636110518112286"

        interaction.user.roles.add(role)
        client.channels.cache.get(warnchannel).send(user + " a été bannis temporairement par: \n \n<@" + interaction.member.id + ">\n \nCar " + raison + "\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        interaction.reply({ content: user + " à bien été temporairement bannis", ephemeral: true })
        user.send("Salut <@" + user.id + ">\nTu as été temporairement bannis, ne quitte pas le serveur, l'équipe de modération va examiner ton cas.\nJ'espère que ce ne soit pas une erreur.\nSi tu n'as rien à te reprocher écris: \"/false\" ici.")
    }
    else {
        interaction.reply({ content: "Tu n'as pas les perms", ephemeral: true, })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line of code gets the desired role (Change `"role name"` to the name of your role).

```js
const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role name");
```

You must add the role to the `GuildMember` class of the target user (the first parameter of your slash command).

To get the `GuildMember` class, from the user ID:

```js
const guildMember = await guild.members.fetch(user.id);
```

Then add the role to the guildMember variable

```js
guildMember.roles.add(role);
```